# The UI Designers and Marketing people at my company don't want "awkward line breaks". How to do with CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have a technical question. I'm a front-end developer and always get requests about changing

> "awkward line breaks"

or

> "too much white space"

or other stuff related to how text of varying lengths wraps onto lines. I'm wondering what CSS and JavaScript I need to prevent text awkwardness. The persons who manage the content want to be able to type any content into the content management system and have it come out non-awkward at every screen size.

Is there a CSS property like

```
text-awardness: non-awkward
```

or

```
line-break: always-look-perfect
```

If not, is there a JavaScript library named something like `awkfixer.js` whereby I can apply a class like

```
<p class="fix-awkardness">Thiiiiiiiiiiiiiisssssssssss word is long and so it might cause a visible space if we're not applying word-break</p>
```

??

Comment: Define "awkward" and "non-awkward" or, at the very least, give us some examples to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by awkwardness, but hyphenation and line-breaks might help here.

CSS3 supports a property called hyphens.

```
hyphens: auto;
```

handling awkward line breaks is a little trickier than a one line fix, but some combination of pseudo elements and margins in your css might do the trick for you.